# jQuery .has() inside click() function showing false result

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I want to detect whether clicked element (link) has img inside it. My non-working code is:

```
$("a").click(function() {
  if ($( this ).has("img")) {
    console.log("link has image inside it");
  } else {
    console.log("no image");
  }
});
```

If you click the text link, .has()things it has img inside it. What am I missing here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because `has()` is used to filter a jQuery object; it does not return a boolean.

To do what you require you would need to use either `find()` or `children()`, depending on the depth you want to check for `img` elements, and then `length`, like this:

```js
$("a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // only for testing

  if ($(this).find("img").length) {
    console.log("link has image inside it");
  } else {
    console.log("no image");
  }
});
```

```css
img { max-width: 300px; }
a { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://google.com">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3a/Cat03.jpg" alt="alt">
</a>

<a href="https://google.com">text link</a>
```